# Cons of Reselect

Tags: reactjs, redux, reselect

#### The main question is simple: What are the cons of [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect)?

According to numerous articles [1](https://hackernoon.com/usage-of-reselect-in-a-react-redux-application-fcdca05cc00d) [2](https://tech.residebrokerage.com/how-we-reselect-and-you-can-to-7e7ed23a8c6f) [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) is a great library that solves a number of problems. And it always sounds like we have to use it.

**But** what you quickly learn during development there is no such thing as "must have" library. You always decide what you should use depends of your needs and resource.

What are the cons of? When I shouldn't use it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's opinion based.

Answer (score 3):

> There are several cons:

1. As reselect recomputes on change in input value. If your input tree is too large, the computation might be expensive too. Hence, it could lead to performance issues.
2. Could face issues like memoized data is not updating on state change or vice versa.

> You shouldn't use it when:

1. You have too large & real time state. Rather than computing data using reselect your state must be organized to carry such computations even if there is some duplicate data. e.g. Application that need high real time data.
2. You don't want to use a store e.g. with react 16.8.x. You can always watch/compute the data using `refs`, `useState` etc or `useReducer` etc.

Comment: To add another con: The selectors are more difficult to write, especially composing them from multiple smaller ones. Reselect often gets introduced and doesn't yield much benefit, because most selections from redux state are not expensive, and the few really slow operations never even get performance-benchmarked. It's added to the stack with the reasoning "it will probably make everything faster" without pinpointing where and how much exactly. Not always worth the added complexity and effort imho.

Comment: If slices of state returned by selector are plain (have no deeply nested objects) and https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks is used (it have handy parameter `shallowEqual` in `useSelector` hook) - in this case with `shallowEqual` the problem dissapears completly, the UI will be re-rendered *only* if one of the props of object returned by selector was changed.